# Aurelia Jspm loading external library

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia, jspm

So I did:

```
$ jspm install github:Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker
$ jspm install npm:moment
```

Then at the top of my js file I did:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import {datepicker} from 'eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker';
import 'eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css!';
```

In my browser it's looking for `/dist/eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` which is returning a `404`, why isn't it using the system map to find out where the actual file is located? Or what ever it is supposed to do....

As a side note, it doesn't do it for `moment.js` like it's supposed to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You installed `Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker` but import from `eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker` (uppercase E vs. lowercase e).

Check in your System config (config.js) what key is used in the map. That is where the loader checks to build the path to the package.

Comment: it's all lower case in the config.js, but the actual file system is uppercase.

Comment: I just did a `jspm install github:Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker` with jspm 0.15.7. In config.js this gives me the mapping `"Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker": "github:Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker@4.15.35"` which is correct.

Either correct your mapping or remove it and install again maybe?

Comment: Fair enough, well I got a bit fed up before you answered so I deleted it all and put angular in instead :/ I assume you are correct though